# Scala: extract the word before a specific character

Tags: string, scala

I have string like this "abc.def ghi.jkl mno.pqr" and would like to extract the word before each "." and have an output string like "abc ghi mno". How do I do this in Scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like this will do

Steps:-

1.Split the string by space delimiter.

2.Map through the Seq of strings created in the first step and split by `.` delimiter.

```
val s = "abc.def ghi.jkl mno.pqr"

val strS = s.split(" ").toSeq

val firstStrS = strS.map { s=>
  val t = s.split('.').toSeq
  t.head
}.mkString(" ")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex to replace characters.

```
val str = "abc.def ghi.jkl mno.pqr".replaceAll("[.]{1}([A-Za-z]){3}", " ")
println(str)
// prints "abc  ghi  mno "
```

Using the `replaceAll()` method, you can then remove duplicate spaces too.